# A query involving Lambert W.

Tags: lambert-w

How do you solve for $x$ in $\frac{N^x}{1.2x(0.25-x)}>\log N$?

It does not seen to succumb to standard techniques.

Is there a good bound on $x$?

Comment: can you tell us something about the variables?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner every variable $>0$.

Comment: i think a numerical method is the only way to solve this

Comment: Lambert W function cannot solve most problems of the form $a^x=bx^2+cx$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how about bounds?

Comment: @SimpleArt how about bounds?

Comment: Well, there exists solutions for $0<x<0.25$, which should be obvious.  Bounds are easier to place if we were told what $N$ was.

Comment: @SimpleArt assume $N\gg 0$.